# how to search google images programatically

Tags: google-image-search

I would like to show google image search results on a web page. A broad web search, not a search of a specific site.

I see that image search api is depreciated. 
I see nothing in the custom search api developer's console that allows me to search for images on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using [this guide](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en)

below is a screenshot of the relevant sections in the control panel

[image: screenshot]